# How to create a new article on an already published android app

Tags: android

I've created an android app where I've published some articles in the form of list. When the user clicks any list item, it will open a new activity. This activity will open an article using webview. So far I've created 40 list items and 40 activities related to each List.

My question is , once i publish the app then if i need to add a new article through an activity then is it possible. If no then how do news apps publish new articles daily?

Answer (score 1):

Apps like CNN or whatever news app generally are client apps getting push API calls from server with read-only privileges. As the author of articles, you write content on a database and serve its with a RESTful API (Or just a Firebase Database). Hint: checkout Firebase's suites of tools.

Answer (score 0):

> I've created...  40 activities related to each List

Poor design. You only need 1  `Article` Java object, and you display each object via 1 generic Activity (or preferably Fragment)

> This activity will open an article using webview

Here's an example

```
public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    public static class Article {
        String title, url;
    } 

    // load article.url into WebView 
}
```

> how do news apps publish new articles daily?

They use external databases and store almost nothing on the app itself